# How can I use peewee db_url.connect() to generate a connection with RetryOperationalError?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I default generate db connection using the PooledMySQLDatabase with RetryOperationalError like this:

```
from playhouse.shortcuts import RetryOperationalError
from playhouse.pool import PooledMySQLDatabase


class MySQLRetryDB(RetryOperationalError, PooledMySQLDatabase):
    pass


mysql_db = MySQLRetryDB('test_db')
```

Now I want to use db_url.connect to generate the db connection like this:

```
from playhouse.db_url import connect
mysql_db = connect('mysql+pool://root:root@localhost:3306/test_db')
```

but I can't find a way to use the RetryOperationalError, How can I use connect() to generate a connection with RetryOperationalError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is hacking the db_url.schemes

```
class MySQLRetryDB(RetryOperationalError, PooledMySQLDatabase):
    pass


schemes['mysql+pool+retry'] = MySQLRetryDB


mysql_db = connect('mysql+pool+retry://root:root@localhost:3306/test_db')
```